# How to modify elasticbeanstalk.conf

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've modified `/etc/httpd/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk.conf` then I've created an AMI image and configured Beanstalk to use this image.

But when the new EC2 instance starts, the config file `elasticbeanstalk.conf` is the original, without my modifications. (Other config files as `httpd.conf` do have my modifications)

How can I modify and persist this file?

EDIT:

This is my modified file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>

  #ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/ retry=0
  #ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/

  # This is my modification
  ProxyPass /j_spring_security_check http://localhost:8080/j_spring_security_check
  ProxyPassReverse /j_spring_security_check http://localhost:8080/j_spring_security_check

  ProxyPreserveHost on

  ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/elasticbeanstalk-error_log
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Can you paste the file and show what you are modifying in the file.

Comment: Just pasted my modified file

Comment: So you are saying you modify beanstalk.conf and take AMI and launch new instance from it you see those changes in https.conf and not in beanstalk.conf ? Is this correct.

Comment: This is a very strange issue the file name is changing here are you sure you are editing elasticbeanstalk.conf and not httpd.conf before creating the AMI?

Comment: In fact I edited both, but only httpd.conf has my modifications after restart.

Comment: Ok many time this happens when you select "No Reboot" while creating the AMI did you select no reboot option while creating the AMI?

Comment: People seems to use .ebextensions for this kind of things... I'll try it

Comment: Not sure, but I can make the AMI again and uncheck no reboot. Thanks

Comment: Yup try it and see if shows the changes in beanstalk.conf

Answer (score 1):

You never, ever, ever, **EVER** do anything on EC2 instances if you are deploying through Elastic Beanstalk (because those instances are ephimeral). In order to properly give the environment an `elasticbeanstalk.conf` file, you:

1. Create a folder `.ebextensions` at the root of your project.
2. Place your `elasticbeanstalk.conf` file (or any other eb configuration files) inside that folder.
3. It probably won't work right away. To force it, on your Elastic Beanstalk console, restart your app server.

This [post](https://zenofchicken.wordpress.com/2015/08/17/setting-the-http-connection-timeout-on-amazon-aws-elastic-beanstalk-tomcat-instances/) explains it further.